# What freelancing jobs I can start without knowledge about it?

Tags: freelance-websites

I don't know coding or photoshop or cannot write but freelancing requires creativeness. Maybe some of you found creative ways to earn some from it. I'm open new ideas :) (also I'm good at typing and fast)

Comment: Freelancing requires that you are able to give some service to someone who is happy to pay you for that. So ask youself what can you offer to other people to solve their problems or needs that they don't wish/know/are able to solve.

Comment: Freelancing is traditionally *never* an "entry-level" profession. I guess you could sell magazines door to door.

Comment: I think I can save people's time. Or I can learn basic stuffs I've seen. Basicly, designing is not hard to learn I can learn convert stuffs. What you've meant was more likely big Gigs. But for cheap gigs (as I hire) people can hire for cheap prices and save their time or effort to learn one-time jobs deeply

Comment: Honestly... If its easy and any body can do it, then why pay you to do it? The higher paid work pays you *not for complexity*, but for responsibility. I have brothers who physically work harder than me, but I earn more (managing projects). If you not care about money or your future, and you want to save people time, and you can learn basic stuff, then try window cleaning, car washing, dish washer. Few people make it a life time choice but its low income and you can get trapped in a job like that (not have enough money to take time off to learn how to do a higher paying job).

Comment: How old are you? Have you finished high school already? What regular jobs have you had? How fast can you type? Can you type as fast as this woman does on her steno keyboard? http://stenoknight.com/ http://www.openstenoproject.org/ If you have neither knowledge nor experience, freelancing is no substitute for a regular job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resisted sarcastic answers, and lots came to mind. But here is some genuine advice because I feel everyone who can should freelance. It is simply a better way of life, which it appears you desire to try.

1. On a piece of paper, write down everything you CAN do (this list may not be very long).
2. Get a few local newspapers and write down all the advertisers, and what they do.
3. Find out what problems they have? You can imagine it, guess at it from the ads (especially the job ads), or call one or two up and tell them you are trying to think up a job small local companies might want you to do and do they have any ideas. You would be amazed, if you have a good attitude and are friendly, open and honest, what people will tell you. (This is along the lines of the classic 'Ask A Fool' approach to creativity). Talk to your family and friends, parents of freinds, neighbours, your local shop keeper, outline your thoughts briefly and get them to make a suggestion. Again, just because someone is a shopkeeper does not mean they do not have some great ideas.
4. Identify what you can do to help these people to solve their problems. Think up a service, put a price to it, then get on the phone or knocking on doors.

Suppose you decide you can cut grass and have access to a lawn mower. Or can deliver leaflets and have a bag. Get out and find someone to pay you to do that. Tell them 'first job is free then it is just x.xx per hour'.

For cutting grass, walk around to find a hotel or a warehouse with overgrown or scruffy external land. Pop in 'Hi, want me to tidy up the front of your factory, can do it tomorrow for just £x, and it will make your visitors think better of you, and make your company look much more attractive.' type of thing.

Now you are a freelancer. Perhaps in five years time you will employ 20 people looking after the maintenance of every business in your local area, perhaps you will have franchised the business, and cover multiple territories, perhaps even delivering landscaping, or building maintenance with teams of electricians, plumbers, cleaners, painters and builders. Who knows where it will lead?

Perhaps one day you will be telling a magazine journalist about how you started out, with a single lawnmower and some initiative, whilst describing how you built your multi million pound empire......

We can all dream, but only a few are brave enough to actually get out there and attempt to make their dreams come true. Go for it. You only live once...

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm appreciate for your answer. I can so many thing but usually they are better to make a course or write a book, which is most likely become passive income they are great though. I will give it a try to finding out ideas for my leisure times. And you're right it's possible for me and everyone to build a multi million pound empire. Thank you for the answer again!

Answer (score 3):

Freelancing jobs without knowledge?

Politics or Prostitution... the latter can be dangerous, the former allows you to achieve a similar service but reach a wider audience and without the risks of an STD or NDE. Both don't look too well on the CV/resume.

Best of luck!